# Can't add information into array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, model, controller

In my rails application I have a model/controller 'Group' that contains the parameters `push_array` and `user_array` . The push_array is being used to save the information into `user_array` through a form. For some reason neither the push array or user array are being saved after entering information into the form. How would I get this to work?

Group Controller

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_group, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :add]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show, :create, :new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :check_groupprivileges!, :only => [:edit, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @groups = Group.limit(3).order("id").all
    respond_with(@groups)
  end

  def show
    @posts = @group.posts.order("created_at DESC")
    @group.user_array << @group.push_array
    @group.save
    @group_id = @group.id
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def add
    @group.user_array << @group.push_array
    @group.save
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def new
    @group = Group.new
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def edit
  end
```

Any help is really appreciated.

```
  def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    @group.save
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def update
    @group.update(group_params)
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def destroy
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @group.destroy
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  private
    def set_group
      @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:id, :group, :group_id, :user, :poster, :posterid)
    end

    def group_params
      params.require(:group).permit(:name, :description, :motto, :usercount, :group, :id, :groupid, :user_array, :user_ids, :usersid, :creatorid, :push_array)
    end
end
```

group/:id/add View

```
<%= form_tag(@group, :method => 'get') do %>
  <strong><%= text_field_tag :push_array, params[:push_array] %><%= submit_tag "Add User" %></strong></br>
  <%= @group.user_array %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what really `user_array`, and `push_array` are?

Answer (score 0):

Parameter sent by form are in `param` variable with model as the key, try to use `@group.user_array << params[:group][:push_array]` instead.

Comment: That says that `group` is not a recognized method for `GroupController`

Comment: Oops. I forgot to use colon. Edited my answer.

Comment: That then says `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`